# calling python3 method from python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to call a python3 method from some specific class inside that python3 module, using python2, have used ***subprocess*** to call, but i am not able to understand how to create object using subprocess and then calling some specific function

**python3 code:**

```
from datetime import date

# random Person
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    @classmethod
    def fromBirthYear(cls, name, birthYear):
        return cls(name, date.today().year - birthYear)

    def display(self):
        print(self.name + "'s age is: " + str(self.age))

person = Person('Adam', 19)
person.display()

person1 = Person.fromBirthYear('John',  1985)
person1.display()
```

**python2 code:**

```
import subprocess
import sys
child = subprocess.Popen("python3 python3.py", stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    out = child.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The creation of object itself i want to do from python2

Comment: There is no way Python 2 code can contain a variable whose value was created by Python 3 code in the sense that you seem to be trying to ask. Your best bet is probably to convert all your code to Python 3. Maybe look at `2to3` and/or the interoperability library `six`.

Comment: The problem is the complete library which I am using is written in Python2, to convert that is quite a huge time taking. And the there is one hardware dependency, where communication can happen only in python3

Comment: The `subprocess` interface you already discovered is probably the best you can do here. It doesn't allow for anything more sophisticated than passing strings (or `bytes`) between processes. Maybe write wrappers on both ends to send JSON back and forth if you need to pass around structured data, or devise your own serialization format if you really have to.

Answer (score 0):

I passed the parameters and function names as arguments, and read them in python3 from cmd line.

**python 2 code**

```
child = subprocess.Popen("python3 f4t_control.py "+self.IP+" get_setpoint", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = child.stdout.read()
return float(out)
```

**python3 code**

```
n=len(sys.argv)
x=F4TController(host=sys.argv[1],timeout=1)
if(n==3):
    if(sys.argv[2]=='get_setpoint'):
        print(format(x.get_setpoint()))
    else:
        x.set_temperature(float(sys.argv[2]))
```

I am able to create the object of python3 class by takking the parameters from cmd line via subprocess